# Why does GHC 7.8 need dynamic libraries?

Tags: haskell, linker, shared-libraries, ghc, static-linking

GHC 7.8 is now dynamically linked by default. [The FAQ](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/GHC-7.8-FAQ) says that this requires GHC to also load *dynamic objects* instead of *static objects*. Now my question is: Why is this the case? Why can't GHC continue to load *static objects*, why does it matter how GHC itself is linked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Release notes for version 7.8.1](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/release-7-8-1.html):

> On Linux, FreeBSD and Mac OS X, GHCi now uses the system dynamic linker by default, instead of its built in (static) object linker. This is more robust cross-platform, and fixes many long-standing bugs (for example: constructors and destructors, weak symbols, etc work correctly, and several edge cases in the RTS are fixed.)

Comment: That might be a another reason why the did this, but the page also says: "when you use a library in GHCi, GHCi must load *dynamic objects*". I'd like to know why this follows from GHC being dynamically linked.

Comment: @bennofs I guess that is because GHCi now using system dynamic linker to link your program dynamically.